# Draft js Editor gets slower as the content increases due to having many decorators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

So my draft-js editor becomes really slow(hacky) the more content I insert (after about 20 decorator replacements). I am guessing this behavior is due to the decorator which checks the entire editor content using regex and replaces the matches with emoji component every time the state changes. I am also creating entities for each of the matches the regex find, I do this by decorating the component with editor state as a prop. Is there a way to make it faster?
Here is my decorator :

```
       {
            strategy: emojiStrategy,
            component: decorateComponentWithProps(RenderEmoji, {
                getEditorState: this.getEditorState,
                setEditorState: this.onChange
            })
        }
```

here is my emojiStrategy :

```
function emojiRegexF(regex, contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
    const text = contentBlock.getText();
    let matchArr, start;

    while ((matchArr = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        start = matchArr.index;

        callback(start, start + matchArr[0].length);
    }
}
function emojiStrategy(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
    emojiRegexF(EMOJI_REGEX, contentBlock, callback, contentState);
}
```

here is my  RenderEmoji component:

```
const RenderEmoji = props => {
    const contentBlock = props.children[0].props.block;
    const emojiKey = contentBlock.getEntityAt(props.children[0].props.start);
    const emojiShortName = props.decoratedText;
    if (!emojiKey) {
        setEntity(props, emojiShortName);
    }

    return (
        <Emoji emoji={emojiShortName} set="emojione" size={24}>
            {props.children}
        </Emoji>
    );
};
```

and here is my setEntity function that sets the entity for the match:

```
function setEntity(props, emojiShortName) {
    const editorState = props.getEditorState();
    const contentstate = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentstate.createEntity(
        "emoji",
        "IMMUTABLE",
        {
            emojiUnicode: emojiShortName
        }
    );

    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const oldSelectionState = editorState.getSelection();

    const selectionState = oldSelectionState.merge({
        focusOffset: props.children[0].props.start + props.decoratedText.length,
        anchorOffset: props.children[0].props.start
    });

    const newContentState = Modifier.applyEntity(
        contentstate,
        selectionState,
        entityKey
    );

    const withBlank = Modifier.replaceText(
        newContentState,
        selectionState,
        emojiShortName + " ",
        null,
        entityKey
    );

    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
        editorState,
        withBlank,
        "apply-entity"
    );

    props.setEditorState(newEditorState);
}
```

Any way I can optimize this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be the source of any real performance problem but there are two things that seem funny:

- Matching the emoji decorator by regex, even though you're creating entities for them.
- Changing the editor state (via `setEntity`) during the rendering of the decorator. Render functions [should be pure](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render).

I imagine you do this type of processing because emojis might be inserted via copy-paste, or via some kind of native emoji picker. A better way would be to:

1. Insert entities for emojis with the `setEntity` logic as part of `onChange` – before the content is saved and ultimately rendered.
2. Use a decorator strategy based on entities only, e.g.:

```js
const emojiStrategy = (contentBlock, callback, contentState) => {
    contentBlock.findEntityRanges(character => {
        const entityKey = character.getEntity();
        return (
            entityKey !== null &&
            contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === 'emoji'
        );
    }, callback);
};
```

Then your decorator component won't need to update the editor state during the rendering. You also might not need to use `decorateComponentWithProps` anymore.

---

Now back to performance – the best way for you to know for sure how to improve it is to [profile your app](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab). You'll be able to tell exactly what takes time to render during keystrokes, and then track down the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a possible solution. Ill look into it.

Comment: one more question, is there a way to make an entity non-editable(other than immutable)? like I have these decorators with emojis short name as text from props.children, so when I go back with a left-arrow in the editor I can still alter the value of the emoji text which ruins the entity and makes the decorator change. What I want is for the emoji image created by the decorator to be seen as a single character and for the user to not be able to edit it much like immutable entity but also none editable. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @AliZeaiter this would probably warrant a separate question instead of a comment. I think I'd try replacing the emoji character(s) with a single space, so the entity is always a single char (like atomic blocks work). If you make the entity `immutable` I don't think it'll be possible for users to change the char.